# How to launch the auth0 login page without explicitly clicking a button in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, auth0

I have recently implemented the auth0 login page by clicking explicitly on the login button. But now I want to trigger the auth0 login page when I type the website url without explicitly clicking on the login button in vue.js. Can someone guide me in this?

Answer (score 0):

just call the auth0 auth method somewhere your components.

first check this tutorial https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs#create-an-authentication-wrapper

then I think you can just call the `loginWithPopup`

like in your `App.vue`:

```
mounted:{
this.loginWithPopup()
}
``
```

Comment: I added the code for mounted. 

mounted: function() {
    console.log('logging in via Auth0!');
    this.auth0login() // a function which does all the auth0 login process. 
}

with this, I am able to access the auth0 login page and even login after entering the user name and password. The issue arises after I have logged in. The login is sucessfull but the page keeps refreshing, thus continuously changing the access token. This is somehow related to the mounted hook which I added in? I do not understand why the page redirected to keep refreshing automatically even after successful login

Comment: you need to handle the page status after you got login result from auth0